# How to set a value to a variable inside ternary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, conditional-operator

Is it possible to set the value of a variable inside a ternary based on a state change?

Something like:

```
{ this.state.change ? myObj.changeIt = true : null }
```

writing it like this returns an error:  `Assignment to property of function parameter 'myObj'`

Comment: That seems to be more a linting warning/error about mutating a function parameter and not about using the ternary.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the entire function the currently specified snippet is in, it should make more clear and provide more context what you are trying to do and what the error is asking you to do.

Answer (score 5):

You need parenthesis for an assignment inside of a ternary, because you have some expressions left hand side.

```
this.state.change ? (myObj.changeIt = true) : null;
```

Beside that, you better take a imperative style.

```
if (this.state.change) myObj.changeIt = true;
```

Comment: it seems that it doesn't accept using if statements inside JSX ( `{ ... }`). It throws the error: Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: if `this.state.change` a boolean? can `myObj.changeIt` be `false`?

Comment: If this is within a `jsx` then you're probably doing it wrong since the expression doesn't return any elements. You better use the imperative style as @NinaScholz mentioned inside your `render` function and before the `return` statement.

Comment: @NinaScholz, `myObj.changeIt` can be `true` or `false. I think it is from ESLint, it doesn't let to write an if statement there